# Does SSML increase Google Text-to-speech quota usage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I have a little indie project that uses the TTS API, and want to make use of SSML to change the way the text is read in some circumstances, but trying to stay under the 4M chars/month quota to avoid getting charged (potentially a bunch of) money.

I'm wondering if all the markup counts towards the quota, but can't find any detailed information about this.

Example:
(21 chars)

```
This is a test. Boop!
```

vs.
(141 chars)

```
<speak>This is a <prosody rate="50%">test.</prosody> <audio src="https://some website/boop.wav">Boop!</audio></speak>
```

As I can't actually see anything about character usage when I check the console, (always says "No data for this period") I never actually know in a given month how close I am to exceeding that limit. So if adding support for this would increase quota usage by a factor of ~5x, I'd like to know.

Quota of requests per minute: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BpIkF.png
Count of chars in all requests: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfuKe.png

Also, if anybody happens to know what's up with that char-count thing, I'd be interested in hearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this [Text-to-Speech pricing GCP Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/pricing), Speech Synthesis Markup Language (SSML) tags are also included in the character count for billing, so you may have to increase your quota accordingly. For best practices and tips and using SSML in Text-to-Speech, you can refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/ssml#tips_for_using_ssml).